# Alarm manager with alert dialog in service

Tags: android, service, notifications, alarmmanager

i m developing 1 app in which i use alarm manager my code is displayed below.actually the problem is that i m successfully created alarm for 1 task that stored in sqlite database (task ,date and time is set by user).,but i m not set **multiple alarms** in this .and my next issue is that **i want to display alert dialog box when alarm has been fired by service** .i m already apply music and vibration at the time of alarm fired and also generate notification too,but the issue is that hoe **to stop that music in my service** .

in general my issue is that

> i want to stop music on notificatoin has been cancled by the user,till that time i want to play music.
>   i want to set alert dialog when alarm has been fired

thanx in advance...any suggestion is appreciate ..!!
my code is displayed below..

```
Myservice.java

public class MyService extends Service {
    /*---String result;
    String oid1,operatorid1;*/


    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
    public String tableName = db.TABLE_CONTACTS;

    public String task_name = db.KEY_TASK;
    public String dt = db.KEY_DATETIME;
    String tname, dt1;
    NotificationManager nm;
    static final int uniqueID = 1394885;
    ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler;
    SQLiteDatabase dbobject;
    Cursor c;
    Context context, ctx1;

    public int flag1 = 0 ,flag2=0;

    public MediaPlayer music;

    public Vibrator vibrator;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        final Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance();
        int hour = c1.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int minutes = c1.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        int day = c1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        int month = c1.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int year1 = c1.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        String combine = String.valueOf(day).trim() + ":"
                + String.valueOf(month + 1).trim() + ":"
                + String.valueOf(year1).trim() + String.valueOf(hour) + ":"
                + String.valueOf(minutes);
        String combine2 = String.valueOf(day).trim() + ":"
                + String.valueOf(month + 1).trim() + ":"
                + String.valueOf(year1).trim() + String.valueOf(hour) + ":"
                + String.valueOf(minutes - 1);

        Log.w("trace", "date   " + combine);
        Log.w("trace", "date   " + combine2);

        // dbobject=this.openOrCreateDatabase("engdb.db",SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY,null);
        MainActivity act = new MainActivity();

        dbobject = act.getInstance().openOrCreateDatabase("contactsManager",
                SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY, null);

        String q = "SELECT task_name,date_time FROM contacts WHERE date_time='"
                + combine + "'";

        c = dbobject.rawQuery(q, null);
        System.out.print("totle records are :" + c.getCount());




        // method1
        if (c.getCount() >= 1) {
            c.moveToFirst();
            try {
                for (int i = 0; i < c.getCount(); i++) {

                    tname = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("task_name"));
                    dt1 = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("date_time"));
                    c.moveToNext();

                }
                flag1 = 1;

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        Log.w("trace", "alarm has been fired " + c.getCount() + "    " +tname
                + "   " +dt1);




        /*if (flag1 == 1) 
        {*/ 
        if(c.getCount()>=1)
        {
            music = MediaPlayer.create(MyService.this, R.raw.mymusic);
            music.start();

            Log.w("trace", "~~~~~~~~music has been start~~~~~~~ ");
            Vibrator vib = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
            vib.vibrate(500);
        //  vib.cancel();
            Log.w("trace", "******vibrator is going to on ******");

            nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            nm.cancel(uniqueID);


            Intent myintent= new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);

            myintent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP| Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
         /*
            myintent.putExtra("notift", "ticketnotif");
            myintent.putExtra("ticketid", str1);*/

            PendingIntent pi=PendingIntent.getActivity(this.getApplicationContext( ),0, myintent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT );
            String body=tname;
            String title ="Wake up !!";
            Notification n= new Notification(R.drawable.img,body,System.currentTimeMillis());
            n.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

            n.setLatestEventInfo(this.getApplicationContext(),title, body,pi);
            n.defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_ALL;

            nm.notify(uniqueID,n);






        }



    }






    public void setDatabase(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        this.dbobject = db;
    }
}// end of IF condition
// end of start method


DatabasedHandler.java

    public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    // All Static variables
    // Database Version
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    // Database Name
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "contactsManager";

    // Contacts table name
    public static final String TABLE_CONTACTS = "contacts";

    // Contacts Table Columns names
    public static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    public static final String KEY_TASK = "task_name";
    public static final String KEY_DATETIME = "date_time";
    Context ctx;
    public List<Contact> contactList = new ArrayList<Contact>();

    public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        ctx = context;
    }

    // Creating Tables
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CONTACTS + "("
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_TASK + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_DATETIME + " TEXT" + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);
    }

    // Upgrading database
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // Drop older table if existed
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_CONTACTS);

        // Create tables again
        onCreate(db);
    }

    /**
     * All CRUD(Create, Read, Update, Delete) Operations
     */

    // Adding new contact
    public void addContact(Contact contact) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_TASK, contact.getName()); // Contact Name
        values.put(KEY_DATETIME, contact.getPhoneNumber()); // Contact Phone

        // Inserting Row
        db.insert(TABLE_CONTACTS, null, values);
        db.close(); // Closing database connection
    }

    // Getting single contact
    Contact getContact(int id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_CONTACTS, new String[] { KEY_ID,
                KEY_TASK, KEY_DATETIME }, KEY_ID + "=?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.moveToFirst();

        Contact contact = new Contact(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
                cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2));
        // return contact
        return contact;
    }

    // Getting All Contacts
    public List<Contact> getAllContacts() {
        try {
            List<Contact> contactList = new ArrayList<Contact>();
            contactList.clear();
            System.out.print("clear array list :");

            // Select All Query
            String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS;

            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

            // looping through all rows and adding to list
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    Contact contact = new Contact();
                    contact.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                    contact.setName(cursor.getString(1));
                    contact.setPhoneNumber(cursor.getString(2));
                    // Adding contact to list
                    contactList.add(contact);
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }

            cursor.close();
            // return contact list
            return contactList;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            Log.e("all_contact", "" + e);
        }
        List<Contact> contactList = new ArrayList<Contact>();
        return contactList;
    }

    // Updating single contact
    public int updateContact(Contact contact) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_TASK, contact.getName());
        values.put(KEY_DATETIME, contact.getPhoneNumber());

        // updating row
        return db.update(TABLE_CONTACTS, values, KEY_ID + " = ?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(contact.getID()) });
    }

    // Deleting single contact
    public void deleteContact(Contact contact) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(TABLE_CONTACTS, KEY_ID + " = ?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(contact.getID()) });
        db.close();
    }

    // Getting numbers of contacts Count
    public int getContactsCount() {
        String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
        cursor.close();

        // return count
        return cursor.getCount();
    }

}



Mainactivity.java

    public class MainActivity extends Activity  implements OnClickListener{
    // This is a handle so that we can call methods on our service
    // This is the date picker used to select the date for our notification
    private DatePicker picker;
    private TimePicker timePicker1;


    DatePickerDialog mDatePickerDialog;
    Calendar c;

    Button b1,b2,b3,b4,b5;
    TextView t1,t2;
    EditText task;


    NotificationManager nm;
    static final int uniqueID=1394885;
    PendingIntent operation;
    Context ctx;

    private int hour;
    private int minutes;
    private int day;
    private int month;
    private int year1;

    static final int TIME_DIALOG_ID = 999;
    static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 1000;
    static MainActivity INSTANCE;
    DatabaseHandler db;

    // DBAdapter2 db2;
     SQLiteDatabase dbobject;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        setCurrentTimeOnView();
        addListenerOnButton();
        INSTANCE=this;
        //dbobject=this.openOrCreateDatabase("engdb",SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY,null);//for ddmmyyyy
    //  dbobject=this.openOrCreateDatabase("engdb2",SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY,null);// for hhmm

        task=(EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.txt_task);
        b1=(Button)this.findViewById(R.id.btndate);
        b2=(Button)this.findViewById(R.id.btntime);
        t1=(TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.lbldate);
        t2=(TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.lbltime);

        b3=(Button)this.findViewById(R.id.selectButton);
     //   b4=(Button)this.findViewById(R.id.updateButton);
        b5=(Button)this.findViewById(R.id.refreshButton);


        db= new DatabaseHandler(this);
      //for the notification
            nm =(NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
              nm.cancel(uniqueID);


              //remove this comments ..................................................................

              db.addContact(new Contact("Ravi", "9100000000"));
              // for the service
             Intent  myIntent = new Intent (this,MyService.class);

              operation = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, myIntent, 0);
              this.ctx=this;
              myIntent.putExtra("operation", operation);
            // Service to check every 1 minute
                AlarmManager manager = 
                        (AlarmManager)ctx.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                Calendar futuretime = Calendar.getInstance();

                futuretime.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
                futuretime.add(Calendar.MINUTE,1);
                manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, futuretime.getTimeInMillis(), 60*1000, operation);

            // End Service...


            /*// context variable contains your `Context`
                AlarmManager mgrAlarm = (AlarmManager) ctx.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                ArrayList<PendingIntent> intentArray = new ArrayList<PendingIntent>();

                for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
                {
                   Intent intent = new Intent(ctx, OnAlarmReceiver.class);
                   // Loop counter `i` is used as a `requestCode`
                   PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ctx, i, intent, 0);
                   // Single alarms in 1, 2, ..., 10 minutes (in `i` minutes)
                   mgrAlarm.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, 
                                SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 60000 * i, 
                                pendingIntent); 

                   intentArray.add(pendingIntent);
                }*/

     /*   
       b4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {       @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                Intent myintent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,displaytask_2.class);
                MainActivity.this.startActivity(myintent);          
            }
        });
        */

        b5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {           
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {

                final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
                minutes = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
                day = c.get (Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
                month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                year1 = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);



                // set current time into textview
                t2.setText(
                            new StringBuilder().append(pad(hour))
                                               .append(":").append(pad(minutes)));

                t1.setText(
                        new StringBuilder().append(pad(day))
                                           .append(":").append(pad(month + 1)).append(":").append(pad(year1)));

                task.setText("");
            }
        });

        //for notification



       // mDatePickUp = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btndate);

     //   db2 = new DBAdapter2(this,"engdb2",null,1);






      //  db.getWritableDatabase();
       // db2.getWritableDatabase();

        c = Calendar.getInstance();

        // Create a new service client and bind our activity to this service

        // Get a reference to our date picker

       // picker = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.scheduleDatePicker);
        }//onCreate() closed


 // display current date and time
    public void setCurrentTimeOnView() {

        t1=(TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.lbldate);
        t2=(TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.lbltime);


        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        minutes = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        day = c.get (Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        year1 = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);



        // set current time into textview
        t2.setText(
                    new StringBuilder().append(pad(hour))
                                       .append(":").append(pad(minutes)));

        t1.setText(
                new StringBuilder().append(pad(day))
                                   .append(":").append(pad(month + 1)).append(":").append(pad(year1)));




    }




    public void addListenerOnButton() {


        b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btndate);

        b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

              showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
            }

        });


        b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btntime);

        b2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                showDialog(TIME_DIALOG_ID);

            }

        });
    }






    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id) {
        case TIME_DIALOG_ID:
            // set time picker as current time
            return new TimePickerDialog(this, 
                                        timePickerListener, hour, minutes,false);

        case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
            // set time picker as current time
            return new DatePickerDialog(this, 
                                        datePickerListener, day, month , year1);
        }
        return null;
    }
   //++++++++++++++++

    //date and time from dialog boxes and save in to sqlite db.......

    private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener datePickerListener =
            new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() 
          {

                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                        int dayOfMonth) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    year1 = year;
                    month = monthOfYear;
                    day = dayOfMonth;


                    /*String insertQuery="insert into contact (Day,Month,Year) values('" +
                    day + "','" + month + "','" +year + "')";
                    db.insertRecord(insertQuery);               
                    int count = db.countRecord();*/
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Date Saved successflly" , 1000).show();


                    t1.setText(new StringBuilder().append(pad(day))
                            .append(":").append(pad(month + 1)).append(":").append(pad(year1)));

                }

            };




    private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener timePickerListener = 
                new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
            public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int selectedHour,
                    int selectedMinute) {
                hour = selectedHour;
                minutes = selectedMinute;

                /*String insertQuery="insert into contact (Hour,Minutes) values('" +
                hour + "','" + minutes + "')";
                db.insertRecord(insertQuery);               
                int count = db.countRecord();*/
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Time Saved successflly" , 1000).show();



                // set current time into textview
                t2.setText(new StringBuilder().append(pad(hour))
                        .append(":").append(pad(minutes)));

            }
        };






            private static String pad(int c) 
            {
                if (c >= 10)
                   return String.valueOf(c);
                else
                   return "0" + String.valueOf(c);
            }


    public void onDateSelectedButtonClick(View v)
     {
        if(task.getText().toString().length()==0) 
        {
            task.setError("Please Enter your Task .."); 
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " fill up the detail correctly ", 2000).show();
        }

        else 
        {
        final ProgressDialog myPd_ring=ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "Please wait", "Alarm has been set...!!", true);
        myPd_ring.setCancelable(true);
        myPd_ring.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        new Thread() {

            public void run() {

            try{

            sleep(1000);

            } catch (Exception e) {

            Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());

            }
            // dismiss the progress dialog
            myPd_ring.dismiss();
            }
            }.start();  





        String set_date = t1.getText().toString();
        String set_time = t2.getText().toString();
        String set_task=task.getText().toString();



       // substring(startIndex, endIndex); 
        String d1=set_date.substring(0,2);
        String m1=set_date.substring(3,5);
        String y1=set_date.substring(6,10);
        String h1=set_time.substring(0,2);
        String min1=set_time.substring(3,5);

        //inser data in to sqlite data base

        String dt= String.valueOf(day).trim()+":"+String.valueOf(month+1).trim()+":"+String.valueOf(year1).trim()+String.valueOf(hour)+":"+String.valueOf(minutes);


        Toast.makeText(getInstance(), "Combine  String   "+dt,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        db.addContact(new Contact("Ravi", "9100000000"));
        db.addContact(new Contact(set_task, dt));


        Toast.makeText(this, " query fired ", 2000).show();


        System.out.println(" message" + d1);


        int day = Integer.parseInt(d1);
        int month = Integer.parseInt(m1);
        int year = Integer.parseInt(y1);
        int hourOfDay = Integer.parseInt(h1);
        int minute = Integer.parseInt(min1);



        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

        //c.set(year, month, day);
        c.set(year, month, day, hourOfDay, minute);
          Toast.makeText(this, "Notification set for the date: "+set_date , 1000).show();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Notification set for the time: "+set_time , 2000).show();

        }

    }

    MainActivity getInstance()
    {
        return INSTANCE;
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If your music is in the service use `stopSelf();` or use

```
if(music.isPlaying()){
music.stop();
music.release();
}
```

That should stop the music from playing.

Comment: :thank u very much.apart from this i want to continuously play music in my service class .!!is this possible ?plz suggest me..